# Does GLfixed over GLint and GLfloat over float make sense?

Tags: opengl, typedef

I know that size of an `int` differs from CPU to another

- 2 bytes for 16-bit machines
- 4 bytes for 32-bit machines

Since we're talking to the **GPU** and not the **CPU**, We use `GLint` when passing **OpenGL** parameters, which is defined as

```
typedef int GLint
```

but there's `GLfixed`

`GLfixed` is defined as a `GLint`

```
typedef GLint GLfixed
```

I have a doubt that it can be used for a specific task or it has nothing to do rather than a reference to `GLint`

about floating numbers **GL** uses

```
typedef float GLfloat
```

a **float**, as I read it's a size of `4 bytes`, So I *think* it's a constant which **does not matter** if I'd use `GLfloat` **or** `float`, they'd be the same number of **4** bytes or maybe `GLfloat` have more to do?

**So**, Does it make sense if I used **GLint** over **GLfixed**, a normal **float** over **GLfloat**?

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, sorry, I meant 16-bit machine, just mis-write, and No, that's how `int`s `size` work, 16 bit = 2 bytes, 32bit = 4 bytes if that's the issue to the downvoter, sorry again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GL spec does define the types it is going to use, and the requirements on the representation.

The fact that `GLint` is an alias of `int` *on your platform* can by no means be generalized. `GLint` will always meet the requirements of the GL, while `int` can vary per platform / ABI.

The same is true for `GLfloat` vs. `float`, although in the real world, virtually every platform capable of OpenGL will use 32 bit IEE754 single precision floats for `float`.

> Does it make sense if I used GLint over GLfixed?

No. `GLfixed` is semantically a type meant for representing *fixed point* 16.16 two's complement values.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm sure it has something to do with its value or it's just **useless** and a **waste of memory** to get multiple definitions of the **same** type

It is neither.

1. As you've pointed out, the bitsize of C and C++ types are not fixed by the C or C++ standards. However, the *OpenGL* standard does fix the OpenGL-defined types. You see `typedef int GLint;` *only* on platforms where `int` is a 32-bit, 2's complement signed integer. On platforms where `int` is smaller, they use a different type in that definition.
2. The visible typenames for a type are hardly useless. Even if you were absolutely certain that `int` and `GLfixed` were the same type, seeing `GLfixed` carries *semantic* meaning beyond `int`. `GLfixed` means to interpret the integer as a 16.16-bit fixed-point type. It is technically an `int`, but any OpenGL API that interprets a value as `GLfixed` will interpret it as a 16.16-bit fixed-point type.
3. Typedefs *don't take up memory*. They're pure syntactic sugar; their use or lack thereof will not make your program take up one byte more or less of storage.

The same applies to `float` and `GLfloat`.

> **So**, Does it make sense if I used **GLint** over **GLfixed**, a normal **float** over **GLfloat**?

You should use OpenGL's types when talking to OpenGL. When not talking directly to OpenGL, that's up to you.